# Pegar URL da página que chamou o arquivo com jQuery .load()

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma função PHP:

```
if( !function_exists('site_url_full') ) {
    function site_url_full() {
        $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $PHPSELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $path = pathinfo( $PHPSELF );
        $diretorio = $path['dirname'];
        $diretorio = "";
        if(is_dir(PATH)) {
            $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $diretorio;
        } else {
            $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        }
        return $url . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
}
```

Uso para 'pegar' a URL completa da página mas quando ela é chamada dentro de um arquivo que é chamado em um evento com jQuery .load(); a URL pega é a do arquivo, não sei como fazer para chamar a URL que chamou o arquivo, e preciso que essa função seja executada dentro do arquivo carregado, tem algum modo para pegar a URL principal pelo arquivo carregado? Pois a URL é inclusa dentro de um input*hidden do arquivo requisitado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`. Irá retornar a URL da página que chamou o AJAX, e não da página PHP requisitada.

Comment: Obrigado por isso rs =)